# How to mock RTCPeerConnection - test onicecandidate

Tags: angular

I have this piece of code:

```
myClass {
  myFunction() {
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] });
    pc.onicecandidate = ice => {
      console.log('Hello world');
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to test (call `expect`), whether the `console.log` has been called? I check it directly:

```
describe('myFunction', () => {
  it('should call console', () => {
    const consoleSpy = spyOn(console, 'log');

    component.myFunction();

    expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

But this obviously doesn't work.